# asyncTask update a static value which is used by OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-asynctask

I m writing an app containing an `asyncTask` which continuously (every seconds or so) adds a value to an `ArrayList<Float>` (declared `static`).

The value is a measure in inches that I want to plot.
In order to do that I have implemented a solution with **OpenGL ES**.
And every time I add a new value my `AsynTask` calls the `requestRender()` method.
Then the `drawRenderer()` take the `ArrayList<Float>` and draw lines with it.

At this point everything works perfectly fine.

I also want that the user can pinch-zoom and move the plot. So I have a `TouchsurfaceView` which also calls `requestRender()` when needed.
Most of the time it works, but time to time I get an error because of concurrent requests for the `ArrayList<Float>` (almost sure of that).

Any ideas How can I solve this ? I see `lock` and `synchronized` stuff, but can t find how to properly use them for my case.

Thanks for reading me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all the updates to the static variable in a synchronized static method and use only that for making updates.